# Multiple arrays within a for loop

Tags: java

I've been working on a small bit of code that helps me calculate performance of a movie's Box-Office weekend. I want it to require the

1. Name of the movie
2. How much it'll cost to use
3. How much it's predicted to make that weekend

Then I want it to output all the above information, with the addition of each movie's performance. Well, I'm having issues with it saving multiple `String[]` values as well as `int[]` values. I can remove the `String` lines, and all the `int[]`'s (both the price and the prediction) work fine, or I can remove the `int[]`'s and the `String[]` works fine. Can anyone help me find my errors?

```
import java.util.*;
public class FMLArrays {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      String[] movieName = new String[15];
      int[] moviePrice = new int[15];
      int[] moviePrediction = new int[15];
      int[] moviePreformance = new int[15];

      for (int i = 0; i < movieName.length; i++) {         

         System.out.print("Enter the name of movie " + (i+1) + ": ");
         movieName[i] = console.nextLine();

         System.out.print("Enter the price of movie " + (i+1) + ": ");
         moviePrice[i] = console.nextInt();

         System.out.print("Enetr the prediction of movie " + (i+1) + ": ");
         moviePrediction[i] = console.nextInt();

         moviePreformance[i] = Math.round(((moviePrediction[i] * 1000000) / moviePrice[i]) * 100) / 100;

         System.out.println();

      }

      for (int i = 0; i < movieName.length; i++) {

         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Name: " + movieName[i]);
         System.out.println("Price: $" + moviePrice[i]);
         System.out.println("Prediction: $" + moviePrediction[i] + " million");
         System.out.println("Preformance: $" + moviePreformance[i]);

      }

   }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use multiple arrays, but create a `Movie` class to hold this information. --- "*Can anyone help me find my errors?*" - Which errors? What isn't working? Why is it not working (Compiler Error? Exception? Unwanted behaviour?)? Please be precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you used nextInt() and entered a number you also enterd a new line character, so the next time you called nextLine() this new line character was your next input waiting.
You could fix this by always using nextLine, or by adding a call for nextLine.

```
import java.util.*;
public class FMLArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] movieName = new String[2];
        int[] moviePrice = new int[2];
        int[] moviePrediction = new int[2];
        int[] moviePreformance = new int[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < movieName.length; i++) {

            System.out.print("Enter the name of movie " + (i+1) + ": ");
            movieName[i] = console.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter the price of movie " + (i+1) + ": ");
            moviePrice[i] = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enetr the prediction of movie " + (i+1) + ": ");
            moviePrediction[i] = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());

            moviePreformance[i] = Math.round(((moviePrediction[i] * 1000000) / moviePrice[i]) * 100) / 100;

            System.out.println();

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < movieName.length; i++) {

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Name: " + movieName[i]);
            System.out.println("Price: $" + moviePrice[i]);
            System.out.println("Prediction: $" + moviePrediction[i] + " million");
            System.out.println("Preformance: $" + moviePreformance[i]);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I looked into why this happens, and decided to make the String[] have a while statement afterwards to search until the output until the line is greater than 0. I didn't want to make each int[] a nextLine because I didn't want to let the user input anything other than a number.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue:

```
moviePrice[i] = console.nextInt();
console.nextLine();

moviePrediction[i] = console.nextInt();
console.nextLine();
```

console.nextInt() only reads the number, not the rest of the line, like carriage return.